# migration to AndroidX exception

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

I am migrating a project to `AndroidX` and have this strange exception.

**How do I find which library causes this?**

There is mentioned `com.android.tools:common:26.3.0` and `android.support.design.widget` but I do not really understand that
These are `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.6.0"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayServicesVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0"

    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1"
    implementation "com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.3.0"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0'

    implementation 'org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.2.1'
    implementation 'org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.2.1'

    implementation 'com.github.ajalt:timberkt:1.5.1'

    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:2.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseCoreVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseMessagingVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:$firebaseVisionVersion"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.7.1'

    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.5"

    // The Apache Commons Text
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-runtime:$navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation"


    //implementation "com.scandit.datacapture:core:$scandit_version"
    //implementation "com.scandit.datacapture:barcode:$scandit_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

ERROR:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools\common\26.3.0\1d9b4db75bbe5fe357c8a56db506f2361ebd508d\common-26.3.0.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools\common\26.3.0\1d9b4db75bbe5fe357c8a56db506f2361ebd508d\common-26.3.0.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1634)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1606)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.getArtifacts(ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.iterator(ArtifactCollectionWithExtraArtifact.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$wireKotlinTasks$2.invoke(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:230)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$wireKotlinTasks$2.invoke(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:26)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:406)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.setupCompilerArgs(Tasks.kt:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareWithInput$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Tasks.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask_Decorated.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1$1.create(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:341)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1.get(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:72)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:167)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue.call(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.AbstractValidatingProperty.validate(AbstractValidatingProperty.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.validate(DefaultTaskProperties.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform artifact 'common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.lambda$visitArtifact$1(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.visitArtifact(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant$SingleArtifactSet.visit(ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformCompletion.visit(TransformCompletion.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.CompositeResolvedArtifactSet$CompositeResult.visit(CompositeResolvedArtifactSet.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$500(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:231)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$200(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1628)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools\common\26.3.0\1d9b4db75bbe5fe357c8a56db506f2361ebd508d\common-26.3.0.jar.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$1(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.mapFailure(Try.java:182)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$3(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:194)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:54)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4717)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3444)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2152)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2042)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3850)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4712)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.invoke(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.lambda$transform$0(TransformationStep.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Success.flatMap(Try.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.transform(TransformationStep.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$InitialTransformationNode$1.transform(TransformationNode.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:229)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$InitialTransformationNode.execute(TransformationNode.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNodeExecutor.execute(TransformationNodeExecutor.java:37)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools\common\26.3.0\1d9b4db75bbe5fe357c8a56db506f2361ebd508d\common-26.3.0.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.LegacyTransformer.transform(LegacyTransformer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$TransformerExecution.execute(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:274)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:148)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.AmbiguousStringJetifierException: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.CoreRemapperImpl.rewriteString(CoreRemapperImpl.kt:91)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.asm.CustomRemapper.mapValue(CustomRemapper.kt:75)
    at org.objectweb.asm.commons.ClassRemapper.visitField(ClassRemapper.java:113)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readField(ClassReader.java:883)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:694)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.ByteCodeTransformer.runTransform(ByteCodeTransformer.kt:39)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:443)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.ArchiveFile.accept(ArchiveFile.kt:49)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:425)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.Archive.accept(Archive.kt:76)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transformLibrary(Processor.kt:421)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:247)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:113)
    ... 81 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
22 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 14 up-to-date
```

Comment: Use androidx.navigation:navigation libraries and use ./gradlew app:dependencies to check the tree of dependencies in your app.

Answer (score 2):

add this line in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

also replace gradels with androidx 
and for in design gradel add below gradel

```
//material design and design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
```

also check in xml files add all widgets of androidx like below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
...  
>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and also replace gradels from java files as below

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: please check the updated answer and do changes as above I hope it will definitely solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your gradle-wrapper properties are too old. Change distributionUrl to the latest and stable gradle and rebuild the project.As well as change the classpath to the latest one.

Comment: I think it is ok: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.10.0"
        classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.3.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }   and wrapper: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

Comment: check whether you have below line in gradle.properties android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: Are you migrate to the androidX at intermediatestage of your project ?

Comment: In case if you migrate at an intermediate stage the you have to change your UI to the androidx supportable widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Before you migrate to androidx, update your project to API 28 and corresponding gradle dependencies .
This is prerequisite asper developer guide:

Before you migrate, bring your app up to date. We recommend updating your project to use the final version of the support library: version 28.0.0. This is because AndroidX artifacts with version 1.0.0 are binary equivalent to the Support Library 28.0.0 artifacts.

After that do simple menu option as below to automatically migrating your project to androidx :

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

Reference link:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score -1):

Try clicking on the **Gradle** from the sidebar, then under **:app**, click on **assembleDebug** from the dropdown.

This should clarify your error.

Comment: The cmd `assembleDebug` doesn't mean that you are running the task in debug mode, but means that you are using the debug `BuildType` defined in the app. You will have the same stacktrace reported in the question.